# Font icon in SVG doesnt work in IE 11

Tags: javascript, d3.js, fonts, internet-explorer-11

Font icon in an SVG foreign element isn't working in IE11. Though it works in Chrome and Firefox. Here is my code

```
var svg = d3.select('#item svg');

svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 50)
    .attr('cx',100)
    .attr('cy', 100)
    .style('fill', 'lightgray');

svg.append('svg:foreignObject')
            .attr('x', 100)
            .attr('y', 100)
            .append('xhtml:span')
            .attr('class', ' glyphicon glyphicon-glass')
            .style('fill', 'white');
```

If you open [this fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/khanSharp/vyz3dgff/)  in IE 11, you will see no icon on the circle. However html icon (outside of svg) works fine in IE11.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IE does not support the foreignObject tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just use a `<text>` element?

https://jsfiddle.net/vyz3dgff/2/

```
var svg = d3.select('#item svg');
svg.append('circle')
    .attr('r', 50)
    .attr('cx',100)
    .attr('cy', 100)
    .style('fill', 'lightgray');

svg.append('svg:text')
        .attr('x', 100)
        .attr('y', 100)
        .attr('class', 'glyphicon')    // note no glyph selection
        .attr('text-anchor', 'middle') // horizontal alignment
        .attr('dy', '0.5em')           // vertical alignment
        .style('font-size', '48px')
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .text("\ue001");               // glyph as defined in the font
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working in IE. Btw, how do i find text '\ue001' for other icons in http://getbootstrap.com/components/ ?

Comment: Test the icon as you did in the Fiddle, then Inspect it (right-click it, choose relevant option) and you should find in the CSS a `content: \e001` or similar. Take that and use it in `.text()`, but note that you need to add a `u`, so `\e001` becomes `\ue001`.

Comment: Perfect. You are the life saver